# Nuxt middleware call two times

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, middleware

I have a Nuxt SSR application. There is a middleware on the page which should check token in query string and it it is not there then redirect to new url with token. It seems that this middleware is called two times under the same url but with the different result for token check. I dont understand why it is called two times and the result for the same condition is different.

```
/** Create DB item and return token */
async middleware(context) {
    const token = context.route.query.token;
    console.log('token');
    console.log(token);  // First one is ok but the second is undefined.
    if (!token) {
        const result = await context.$api.campaigns.createNewShare();
        context.redirect({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
    }
},
```

This its the screenshot of the request flow:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically because you're using SSR, that middleware is going to be called once from the server and once from the client, hence why you can see duplicated logs.

You can prevent the middleware from being run on the server by using `if (process.client)` or prevent the middleware from being run on the client by using `if (process.server)`.

Example:

```
/** Create DB item and return token */
async middleware(context) {
    if (process.client) {       // or !process.server if you prefer
        const token = context.route.query.token;
        console.log('token');
        console.log(token);  // First one is ok but the second is undefined.
        if (!token) {
            const result = await context.$api.campaigns.createNewShare();
            context.redirect({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I add the process.client condition it is not called at all.

Comment: Could it be that it's already only running on the server-side and that the middleware is being called twice because the first page that's loaded doesn't have the token, which then redirects to another/the same route (which will trigger the middleware again)?

Answer (score -1):

You probably have the middleware defined twice.
Check if you have this in your route (page):

```
middleware: ['yourMiddleware']
```

and this in nuxt.config.js:

```
router: {
  middleware: ['yourMiddleware'],
  ..
}
```

Comment: despite having defined middleware once it called two times